# How to move a Image from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2) linearly (using Animations) [Android]

Tags: android

I need to know how to move a image from one location to another location smoothly. In some tutorials they have asked to move it pixel by pixel calling invalidate() function after waiting for a small time duration.

But isnt there any other way to do it.?

But i need to animate it dynamically. Think that i need to move some image to the location where person touches on screen. I need it to be do using Java, not from XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a animation on XML, load it and use on your view.

Consider it's the file hide.xml (on the res/anim folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="100"
    android:duration="300" android:fillAfter="true" />
```

Then in your Activity you load it and apply to the View you want to translate.

```
Animation hide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.hide);
yourView.startAnimation(hide);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.  But i need to animate it dynamically. Think that i need to move some image to the location where person touches on screen.